# 5 volt output max current for Arduino Mega 2560 rev3

Tags: arduino, output

Well I've looked and looked and just cant find data on the max current of the 5 v output (or even a suggested reasonable max)
They all mention 50 mA for the 3.3v output.
Looking at the chip it's a smaller board than the Arduino Uno so I don't want to pop it.
I assume someone will know the max current that the regulator on this board can handle and surmise what the 5v current out could be? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The regulator / board 5v pin out, not chip related.

EDIT: Assuming supply is from the 12v power adapter.

Comment: I guess it's the same for the two pins then. what do you want to power?

Comment: @ladislas adafruit 1.2" 7-segment LED display with I2C backpack - yea probably be alright for that, but would be good to know if I need to hook up some more sensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [schematic](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega2560_R3-sch.pdf) shows a NCP1117ST50T3G. The [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1117-D.PDF) shows 1500mA (typical).

Note that you may not actually be able to draw that at the higher end of the input voltage range since the Arduino may not provide sufficient heatsinking, needed since the regulator will shut down if it gets too hot (and the regulator will melt down if it doesn't shut down).

Also note that the traces on the board may not be designed to allow that much current to flow safely, and you could end up damaging the board itself regardless.

Comment: Ah well found, It feeds the CPU as well. Based on the track size do u know of a safe assumption of current draw @ 5 volts?

Comment: Nope. But once you find out the trace thickness and width you can put them into any online calculator and get the ampacity. I personally wouldn't try more than 400mA myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on record that you can put any amperage as input as long as the voltage in within range.  So, if you have a 5V 200A high power input you are still fine.  Now, If you have a short, you're cooked.  But a properly designed circuit will draw what it needs and nothing more.

Hyperbole.  I know absolutely nothing about this topic.  I'm hoping a lot of people will call me names and one of those will correct me with a correct electrical engineering based answer.  Either my view is correct or it isn't.